# On click of apply button the content I'm given should save. It is not happening (not saving) here

Tags: xml, odoo-8

When I click on the *Apply* button the content of the form fields should be saved. It is not happening (not saving) here. It should be saved in the same page but without showing any issues.

```
<form>
    <header>
        <button string="Apply" type="object" name="execute" class="oe_highlight"/>
            or
        <button string="Cancel" type="object" name="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
    </header>
    <separator string="settings"/>
    <group>
        <label for="id" string="Name"/>
        <div name="settings_name">
            <field name="name" class="oe_inline"/>
        </div>
        <field name="number" class="oe_inline"/>           
    </group>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the python code of the `execute` method?

Answer (score 1):

This is python code i have used.@forvas

```
  class pr_settings(osv.osv):
          _name="pr.settings"
          _inherit = 'hr.config.settings'
          _descriptions="Settings"
          _columns={
         'name': fields.char('Name',size=128),
         'number':fields.boolean('payslip')     
                      }
```